# Does anyone know how an official Auto-Scroll HTML code?

Tags: html, excel, vba, scroll

I am putting together a local website for my work. I have to use limited resources and excel to publish this site as information updates.

Due to the constantly changing data, I found it was best to have the VBA publish a new HTML file each time the data changes.
Because of this method, I have also put in VBA code to edit the HTML code after it has been published to put in background and refresh for the site.

As to the details of the site, it displays barcodes with data that can be scanned from the screen to activate programs within the scanner.

The issue I predict to have is when the data and barcodes extend beyond the window. I want to have zero interaction from the person holding the scanner as far as key presses, mouse clicks, or wheel scrolling.

All this leads to my question:
I have tried ScrollBy, ScrollTo, window.scroll etc. But these seem to be a one-off action and no further action.
Is there a simple line or lines of code that will slowly scroll the screen down until the times refresh, when it reloads at the top of the screen?

P.S. This will be run in Internet Explorer and possibly Firefox depending on the hardware that can be used for this purpose.

Comment: 1. Pleaes add your code or a [mcve] to your question. • 2. Note that Internet Exploror is dead and not supported anymore. You should really switch to a modern and secure browser. • Actually the question you have could probably only be solved with a JavaScript in the HTML site that auto scrolls the page (or a `div` content). You probably can find one googeling for a autoscroll JS.

Comment: An issue you will probably run into using an auto scrolling page with barcodes: Aiming the correct barcode with the scanner could be difficult if the codes move.

Comment: User will complain that the barcode they need just scrolled off the page.....  Is it not possible to split collections of barcodes in screens, and add an option to switch to 'next screen'?